# Extend rootScope with alert service?

Tags: inheritance, angularjs, dry, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I can easily envision myself injecting my alert service into almost every one of my controllers:

```js
myApp.factory('AlertsList', function () {
    return [{ type: 'info',    msg: 'Welcome!'},
            { type: 'success', msg: 'Checkout this subpage'}]
});

/* E.g.: for this controller */

function AlertsCtrl($scope, AlertsList) {
    $scope.alerts = AlertsList;

    $scope.closeAlert = function (index) {
        $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

AlertsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'AlertsList'];
```

To stop this extended boilerplate; how can I update AngularJS's rootScope with this alert service?

Comment: Hypothetically , why not to do it like `$rootScope.alerts = AlertsList;` ?

Comment: sounds to me like you could make a reusable directive that displays message boxes depending on some application state? I might want to use that code, so please write it! ; )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use $rootScope to store a reference to a service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21789082/use-rootscope-to-store-a-reference-to-a-service)