# Use $rootScope to store a reference to a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a medium / big size application where we have the current user data and methods stored on a Service. Because we need the user info across the application, would it be a bad idea to attach this service to the `$rootScope` once?

In `AppController`:

```
$rootScope.user = user.get();
```

Instead of adding it on a Controller base (which would be in the 95% of the Controllers):

```
$scope.user = user.get();
```

Also, are there any memory / performance implications?

Thanks!

Comment: Service is a singltone. You can just inject it whenever you need user data.

Comment: Yep, that's why `User` is a service now, but we use that service across the application (gets injected in every Controller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store it on `$rootScope`, you will be able to read it in any controller without injecting `$rootScope` due to prototypical inheritance, but the minute someone decides to make a new `$scope.user` property in one of your controllers, you'll lose your reference to the user property on `$rootScope`, unless you have explicitly injected and reference `$rootScope` directly.  That could waste someone's time trying to debug.

I believe convention is that it's acceptable to store data on `$rootScope` but don't store functions there. I wouldn't rely on the prototypical inheritance from child scopes unless, at a minimum, you make a model object on `$rootScope` with a minimal chance of being overridden by a controller, like `$rootScope.globalData.user` or something.